# smart select prevent from displaying options

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

On the example [here](https://framework7.io/docs/smart-select.html), clicking an item on the list will display the list of available options.

So I created a `smart select` element also and add its options in Javascript. In this case, it works fine similar on the link I provided.

But what I want is, instead of showing the list of options, I want the options not to show. I need this especially when there is only one option available or no options available at all. How could I do this?

I tried `event.preventDefault`, but this seems not doing anything.

**View:**

```
<div class="list-block">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="item-link smart-select" data-back-on-select="true" data-navbar-theme="red" data-form-theme="green">
        <select class="test">
        </select>
        <div class="item-content">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">Sample Title</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:** (Add options on my smart select element)

```
myApp.smartSelectAddOption('.test', '<option value="1">Item 1</option>');
myApp.smartSelectAddOption('.test', '<option value="2">Item 2</option>');
myApp.smartSelectAddOption('.test', '<option value="3">Item 3</option>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging the `framework7` library. I found this piece of code.

```
if (select.disabled || smartSelect.hasClass('disabled') || $select.hasClass('disabled')) {
return;
```

}

So in order to NOT display the smart select options we just need to add a class `disabled`

```
$$('.test').addClass('disabled');
```